# Timeseries several events forecasting

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning, time-series, forecasting

I am new to timeseries and I have a problem, I have a dataset of 3 columns, time, category, frequency of this category. The time is from 2016 to end of 2017. I need to forecast the frequency of each category during 2018: Dataset:
[image]

I need to use Neural Prophet to forecast the frequency of these data and I know only how to forecast ds,y. So Please advice on how to do this task using neural prophet

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Neuraprophet docs, here https://neuralprophet.com/model-overview/:

> If you have many series that you expect to produce forecasts for, you
> need to do this one at a time.

In your case you have multiple timeseries i.e. you have a separate timeseries corresponding to each primary_industry. So if you are going to apply neuralprophet on this dataset you will have to fit the model on each industry separately.

Comment: Oh, okay so there is no way even with another framework/library to do it one time for all primary industry?

Comment: You can try lstm using keras. But you have to be careful while preparing the data for it.